# How to distinguish hard symlinks in Windows 7 file explorer

Tags: windows-7

Suppose I have two hard symlinks both pointing at the same file contents. Is there a way to have Windows(File) Explorer show this? I have seen related posts (such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487237/detect-symbolic-links-junction-points-mount-points-and-hard-links) that talk about how to programatically do it or do it from the command prompt, but i haven't seen anything about the Explorer. It would be nice if they were colored or shaded differently or something.

Answer (score 3):

OK, I found the following, called Link Shell Extension, which does what I want and then some. Its an add-on to the file explorer. I hope its useful to others
http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/hardlinkshellext.html